# Problema al utilizar IndexOF (dato no encontrado)

Tags: java, netbeans

Java netBeans

Estoy teniendo un problema a la hora de utilizar el indexOf, mi problema resulta que tengo que introducir forzosamente el texto del indexOF. Por ejemplo estoy buscando la palabra "hola" en el index pero si en el texto no se encuentra me genera error. ¿Como puedo hacer para que si no encuentra la palabra no la tome en cuenta y siga? Les muestro mi linea de codigo donde realizo el index

```
jTextArea3.getText();
String textorem = "Hola"; 
int inicio = myText.indexOf("Hola");
int fin = inicio + textorem.length(); 
jTextArea3.replaceRange("Adios", inicio, fin);
```

Comment: Supongo que te falta filtrar que si el indexOf te devuelve un -1 (porque no encuentra esa palabra) no siga con el fin y el replaceRange. Por otro lado te sugiero usar replace(), ya que este te cambiaría la palabra en caso de que la encuentre sin tener que calcular el inicio y fin.

Comment: Gracias, acabo de probar filtrarlo y logré hacer que no siga si se presenta el -1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

si lo que necesitas es cambiar "hola" por "adios" usa esto:

```
String resultado = jTextArea3.getText().replace("hola", "adios");
```

o si quieres cambiar todos los "hola" por "adios"

```
String resultado = jTextArea3.getText().replaceAll("hola", "adios");
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, me funciono perfectamente